# Make active tab default on StackApps

Tags: script, stackapps

This script changes the logo link to the active tab and redirects from the home page to it on StackApps. If you want to see the list of apps, you can still do this by clicking the **apps** tab. [Made by request.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/79098/change-default-landing-page-on-stackapps)

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/97131.user.js) - [View Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/97131)